# Operator Norm Calculations

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I've been trying to introduce myself to functional analysis and I came across a couple of problems I cannot solve. I would appreciate if someone could provide a hint.

**Definition**

Let $A\in\mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$, we define the *Operator Norm* of $A$ as follows $$||A||_{op}=\sup_{||x||\leq 1}{||Ax||}=\inf{\{t\in\mathbb{R}: ||Ax||\leq t||x||, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\}}$$

**Problems**

1) Let $(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})=x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and define $A_{x}=(a_{ij})$ with $a_{ij}=\begin{cases}a_{ij}=x_{i}, \text{for}\, i=j\\
a_{ij}=0, \text{for}\, i\neq j\end{cases}$

i.e. the matrix whose diagonal elements are the components of $x$ and zeroes elsewhere. Compute $||A_{x}||_{op}$.

2) Let $A\in\mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$. Prove that: $$\inf{\{||A^{n}||^{1/n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}}=\max{\{|\lambda|}\mid \lambda\, \text{is an eigenvalue of A}\}$$

**Attempts**

1) Let $(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})=x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be *fixed*, and $(y_{1},\dots,y_{n})=y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ then $A_{x}y=(x_{1}y_{1},\dots,x_{n}y_{n})^t$, thus $$||A_{x}y||=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}y_{i}^{2}\right)^{1/2}$$ but I then I don't know how to take suprema or infima over $y$.

2) I don't have a single clue where to start.

Thank you in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) With what you have written,
$$
||A_x y || = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 y_i^2\right)^{1/2}
$$
Suppose you demanded $||y||=1$ so $y_1^2 + ...+y_n^2=1$. What's the best way to place weight on the $y$ components so that the sum is as big as possible?

2) Here's the main idea. We say $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue and $x \neq 0$ if $Ax=\lambda x$. Hence, by induction, $A^n x=\lambda^n x$. Now we can say $||A^n x||=|\lambda|^n||x||\leq ||A^n||\, ||x||$. Scaling $x$ so that $||x||=1$ shows $|\lambda|^n\leq ||A^n||$.

The eigenvalue is arbitrary, so this holds for all eigenvalues. Therefore, $\max |\lambda| \leq ||A^n||^{1/n}$. Now that we know $\max |\lambda|$ is a lower bound, the greatest lower bound has to be at least as big.

Hence, $\max |\lambda|\leq \inf\{||A^n||^{1/n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. You finish the proof by showing $\max |\lambda|\geq \inf\{||A^n||^{1/n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ holds.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I figured out that the best way to distribute the weight on the $y$ components was putting $1$ on the largest component of $y$ and $0$ elsewhere. I optimized the function on the unit ball to be sure.  For the second part i tried to use everything I know about this things but my best approximation was $||A^n||\leq (||A||)^n$ so I only have to prove $||A||| \leq \max |\lambda|$ but haven't got it yet.